# Can't connect to Cryptocompare's Websocket and emit requests

Tags: python-3.x, socket.io

I have been trying to connect to [Cryptocompare's WebSocket](https://www.cryptocompare.com/api/): `wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket`

I need to connect to this WebSocket to receive real-time prices. I have tried the following approaches

## 1. Using websocket-client

```
import websocket as ws  
socket = ws.create_connection('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket', timeout = 10) 
socket.connected
```

This returns
`True`

This approach connects me to cryptocompare's websocket but doesn't let me send messages. As per the guidelines from Cryptocompare's API, I used:

`socket.send('SubAdd',{'subs': ['0~Poloniex~BTC~USD']})`

This above code returns this Error:

`ValueError: Invalid OPCODE`

The Javascript code for the same as given in API is :

`socket.emit('SubAdd', { subs: ['0~Poloniex~BTC~USD'] } );`

I don't understand what am I doing wrong

## 2. Using socketIO-client

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

try:
    socket = SocketIO('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket', wait_for_connection=False)
    socket.wait()
except ConnectionError:
    print('The server is down. Try again later.')
```

This gives the following output:

```
ConnectionError: HTTPConnectionPool(host='wss', port=80): Max retries exceeded with url: //streamer.cryptocompare.com/socket.io/transport=websocket/socket.io/?EIO=3&transport=polling&t=1512683258219-0 (Caused by NewConnectionError('<requests.packages.urllib3.connection.HTTPConnection object at 0x7fbd0c273400>: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno -2] Name or service not known',))
```

Any help regarding this issue is appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Oddly enough I'm having the same issue. emit is provided by socket.io and the native Websocket implementation doesn't implement this. Basically what you are missing is you need to call the emit before you setup a subscription.

```
from requests.exceptions import ConnectionError
from socketIO_client import SocketIO

try:
    socket = SocketIO('wss://streamer.cryptocompare.com/socket.io/?transport=websocket', wait_for_connection=False)
    socket.emit('SubAdd', { subs: ['0~Poloniex~BTC~USD'] });
    socket.wait()
except ConnectionError:
    print('The server is down. Try again later.')
```

Here is a working gist using angular if it helps https://gist.github.com/jessemlay/ac856ebe015f408263df9a28787adf6f

Comment: The above code still gives out errors. I have tried this but I have connection error all the time.